# How to convert a little-endian binary to Delphi Record type

Tags: delphi

Is there a way to help convert a binary to a specified record in Delphi 5? And this binary is in little-endian.

Comment: One more question, in the end of my data, it's composed with dynamic length, can they also be copied to a record? Let say, there will be a flag indicating how many group will be repeated, and each group has a fixed size, something like that...

Comment: Yes, Delphi 5 can handle anything you give it.  So can any variant from Turbo Pascal through Delphi XE2.  There are many gotcha's to be aware of, besides simple byte order.  For example: packed vs. unpacked.  Or Pascal strings vs C strings vs fixed length character arrays.  Etc Etc

Comment: If you need repeating items, then simply read or write them using a g stream. Every layout you want is possible. Reading back means you first read the number, then allocate space for them, and then read each item in a loop or read them all in one go. How you do that depends on the layout. Just show the record(s) and types you want to put in a file.

Comment: There are many ways to convert between network byte order and host byte order. But you won't get specific advice until you can aska a specific question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows on Intel/AMD is little-endian too, so no endianness conversion is required.

Now if you can show the specific record and where you get the binary data from, it will be easier to answer.

You can read any kind of record from a file. If your record is declared thus that it has exactly the same layout as the binary data, you can read an entire record at once. If not, you'll have to read each field separately.

Generally, you can read records, or individual fields of a record, from a stream using

```
var
  MyStream: TStream;
...
  MyStream := TFileStream.Create(Filename, options);
...
  MyStream.Read(variable, sizeof(variable));
```

If your data comes from a TCP socket, you can, for instance, write it into a TMemoryStream, as bytes. Then you can reset the pointer of the stream to the beginning and read the data as shown.

### Update

As David commented, if the bytes come over the TCP connection in network byte order, then it makes sense to run each field through one of the WinSock functions *ntohs()* or *ntohl()*, after all the above, but before the items in the record are used. *ntohs()* converts 2 byte types, while *ntohl()* converts 4 byte types. To send items, use the reverse functions *htons()* and *htonl()* on each item in the record before sending them (separately).

FWIW, it is quite easy, in Win32, to change endianness using:

```
// byte swaps 32 bit values
function BSwap32(I: DWORD): DWORD; { inline; }
asm
        BSWAP   EAX
end;

// byte swaps 16 bit values
function BSwap16(I: WORD): WORD; { inline; }
asm
        XCHG    AL,AH
end;

// byte swaps 64 bit values
function BSwap64(I: QWORD): QWORD; { inline; }
asm
        MOV     EDX,[EAX]
        MOV     EAX,[EAX+4]
        BSWAP   EAX
        BSWAP   EDX
end;
```

Comment: yes, i've realized that Windows is little-endian. I just wonder if Delphi5 can handle it correctly or not. And i need a try. Besides, my data is coming from TCP Socket, and need i to decode it to byte array? Or just char array is enough?

Comment: Delphi 5 can handle it correctly, if you know the exact declaration of the data and show us the record. That determines whether it will work, or not. If the data is packed and your record is not, or vice versa, you must read each field separately. Otherwise, you can read an entire record at once (assuming it was declared properly). It all depends on the layout of the data in the file.

Comment: FWIW, **show the data** and, if there are repeating fields (groups) beyond the record, show where. To have people answer your questions, you should give them more information. **Show the data**.

Comment: @rudy If data comes from socket it should be in network byte order and so needs to be converted to host byte order. I think that's probably what is behind the question.

Comment: Negative. Windows is not little-endian, 80x86 platform is. And for networking purposes standard sockets DO provide network-to-host and vice versa conversion routines.

Comment: @Downvoter-etc: But the bytes may come over the network in network byte order (which is big-endian). David is right. But I can only see, in OP's post, that the data are little-endian. Otherwise he'll need something like the WinSock functions ntohl() and noths(), and apply the appropriate one to each field in the record separately.

Comment: @Downvoter-etc: Windows on the x86-32 or x86-64 platforms is little endian too. It would be pretty silly if it were not, but theoretically, it could be big-endian, even on x86, if MS wanted. So I think I can say that Windows (on which Delphi runs) is little-endian.

Comment: Thank you guys, specially for @Rudy, sorry that i cannot show you that sample data, and finally, following your suggestion, issues are solved