# How to convert a record from host to network byte order (big endian)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I have a record:

```
  Tconnecting = record
  var
    a: int64;
    b: integer;
    c: integer;
  end;
```

which I need send to server using UDP protocol

I fill it

```
  packet.a := StrToInt64('0x1234567890');
  packet.b := 0;
  packet.c := RandomRange(1, 9999999);
```

and sending it

```
  SetLength(send_data, sizeof(packet));
  send_data := RawToBytes(packet, SizeOf(packet));
  udp.SendBuffer(make_it_big_endian(send_data)); <-- the question... "network byte order"
```

or maybe I'm doing something wrong? I need to send "bign endian" packet

```
pack("N*", int64, int, int); (this is in PHP)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466205/how-to-convert-a-little-endian-binary-to-delphi-record-type

Comment: After reading the documentation of PHP pack() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php I guess the return value is already big endian on the host side. How are you sending / receiving the data on the PHP side?

Comment: @Jens I read it that OP is wanting to replicate in Delphi what the PHP code does.

Comment: @waza123 Are you writing to a file from PHP and then reading it from Delphi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code is running in a little-endian OS/Machine (like Windows/Intel), you can just reverse the individual bytes of your *packet*, for example, include the FMX.Types unit in your uses clause:

```
type
  Tconnecting = record
    a: int64;
    b: integer;
    c: integer;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Packet, BEPacket: Tconnecting;
begin
  packet.a := $0102030405060708;
  packet.b := $01020304;
  packet.c := $05060708;
  //big endian packet  
  BEPacket := Packet;

  ReverseBytes(@BEPacket.a, SizeOf(BePacket.a));
  ReverseBytes(@BEPacket.b, SizeOf(BePacket.b));
  ReverseBytes(@BEPacket.c, SizeOf(BePacket.c));

  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('a: %16.16x => %16.16x', [Packet.a, BEPacket.a]));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('b: %8.8x => %8.8x', [Packet.b, BEPacket.b]));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('c: %8.8x => %8.8x', [Packet.c, BEPacket.c]));
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are actually doing is converting from host byte order to network byte order. All standard sockets libraries provide helper functions to do that.

For example, Winsock offers htons, htonl etc. And in the opposite direction you have ntohs, ntohl etc. If you are using Indy, then the equivalent functions are `GStack.HostToNetwork` and `GStack.NetworkToHost`.

You should serialize each field into a byte stream, with each field being transformed by the appropriate hton* function. Then you can put the byte stream on the wire.

Comment: I first thought on this, but I failed to find a signed integer version. A fast test using Indy wrappers converted the int64 only, but not the Integers.

Comment: @jachguate You can use htonl. You just need to interpret the value as an unsigned value. Delphi absolute would do it for example.

Comment: Using absolute, I'm now getting b: FFFFFFFF => FFFFFFFF = 01000000 (first is the original packet.b (-1), second using ReverseBytes and third htonl(Abs(b));. How do you have to call it to successfully transform signed integers?, only using casts?.

Comment: I get FFFFFFFF => FFFFFFFF = FFFFFFFF for DWORD(DPacket.b) := htonl(DWORD(DPacket.b));, but it looks ugly to me.

Comment: @jachguate You'd write helper functions to work with signed values. And so hide the ugly.

Comment: PHP: fwrite($fp, pack("N*", 0x1234567890, 0x55, 0x66));

Comment: Using Indy's `GStack` conversion methods is the correct answer. They work fine with signed integers. Indy's own code, like `TIdIOHander.Write(Integer)` and `TIdIOHander.ReadLongInt()`, use them internally.

Comment: htons(pTcpTable.Table[i].dwRemotePort) toi get the corect port