# GStack.HostToNetwork input types - Shortint?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

1. How to pass "a" variable into HostToNetwork() ? Need somehow convert it..
2. And how to insert into "a" variable, this HEX code ?

   ```
   var
   a : array[0..19] of Shortint;
   h : string;

   h =: '714BD6D36D4944F4E4F943CB03D128EA5C372FF6';

   GStack.HostToNetwork(a)
   ```

from IdStack.pas:

```
function HostToNetwork(AValue: Word): Word; overload; virtual; abstract;
function HostToNetwork(AValue: LongWord): LongWord; overload; virtual; abstract;
function HostToNetwork(AValue: Int64): Int64; overload; virtual; abstract;
function HostToNetwork(const AValue: TIdIPv6Address): TIdIPv6Address; overload; virtual;
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
    h := '714BD6D36D4944F4E4F943CB03D128EA5C372FF6';
    for x := 0 to 19 do
    begin
      a[x] := StrToInt('$'+Copy(h, x, 2));
    end;
```

correct ?

Comment: What are you going to do ? I'm asking since the [`HostToNetwork`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=%21%21OVERLOADED_HostToNetwork_TIdStack.html) methods you've listed are all abstract except the last one which just calls the first overload. So in short, they do exactly nothing in the [`TIdStack`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdStack.html) base class.

Comment: im using HostToNetwork to convert my passed data (int/int64 and now need shortint) to "big endian"

Comment: @waza123 for 1-byte size data, byte-endianess is meaningless, since the in-memory representation is the same!!

Comment: @TLama: `GStack` is a `TIdStack` pointer, but it does not point at an actual `TIdStack` object instance. It points at a platform-specific descendant object instead, such as `TIdStackWindows`. `HostToNetwork()` and `NetworkToHost()` are abstract in `TIdStack` itself, but are implemented in those descendants. This is basic polymorphism 101 kind of stuff.

Comment: Sending hex as a string is very strange. You've asked a series of questions that show that your understanding of host and network byte orders is incomplete. What you need is to step back and gain some understanding. If you want to ask a question here, the question you need to ask is one that will give you fundamental understanding. Ask about your underlying problem. Don't ask about your attempted solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Shortint` is 1 byte in size, and as such is not affected by endian at all.  The `GStack.HostToNetwork()` and `GStack.NetworkToHost()` methods only operate on multi-byte integers instead.  So it does not make sense to use the `GStack` methods in this example.  You are declaring an array of 20 raw bytes.  You need to first split those bytes into integers before you can then convert them.  Once you have split them, then you can pass them to `GStack` individually as needed.

Based on your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505211), you are actualy dealing with records of integers, not raw bytes.  You need to convert the integers to network byte order **BEFORE** you encode a record to raw bytes, and then convert the integers to host byte order **AFTER** you have first decoded raw bytes into a record.  For example:

```
type
  Tconnecting = packed record
    a: int64;
    b: integer;
    c: integer;
  end;

var
  packet: Tconnecting;
  send_data: TIdBytes;
begin
  packet.a := $1234567890;
  packet.b := 0;
  packet.c := RandomRange(1, 9999999);

  packet.a := GStack.HostToNetwork(packet.a);
  packet.b := Integer(GStack.HostToNetwork(LongWord(packet.b)));
  packet.c := Integer(GStack.HostToNetwork(LongWord(packet.c)));

  send_data := RawToBytes(packet, SizeOf(packet));
  udp.SendBuffer(send_data);
end;
```

.

```
var
  Treply = packed record
    c: integer;
    b: integer;
    a: int64;
  end;

var
  packet: Tconnecting;
  received_data: TIdBytes;
begin
  SetLength(received_data, SizeOf(Treply));
  if udp.ReceiveBuffer(received_data) = SizeOf(Treply) then
  begin
    BytesToRaw(received_data, packet, SizeOf(Treply));

    packet.a := GStack.NetworkToHost(packet.a);
    packet.b := Integer(GStack.NetworkToHost(LongWord(packet.b)));
    packet.c := Integer(GStack.NetworkToHost(LongWord(packet.c)));

    // use packet as needed ...
  end;
end;
```