# How to convert from long to two-complement, big-endian Tbytes in delphi

Tags: java, delphi, twos-complement, endianness

Please help me translating Java code to Pascal.

Comment: prepare data here, 8 bytes are used for the turnover counter (more then enough for every possible turnover...), however the specification only requires 5 bytes at a minimum bytes 0-7 are used for the turnover counter, which is represented by 8-byte two-complement, Big Endian representation (equal to Java LONG), bytes 8-15 are set to 0 negative values are possible (very rare)

```
Long turnoverCounter = 50501;
ByteBuffer byteBufferData = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
byteBufferData.putLong(turnoverCounter);
byte[] data = byteBufferData.array();  

// data result = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -59, 69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

java byteBuffer Data.putLong interested in Pascal

Thank you.

Comment: Java writes a `long` (not a `Long`) as 8 bytes in Big Endian by default.

Comment: "the specification only requires 5 bytes" which 5 bytes are you thinking of, can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Individual bytes being negative seems likely to me. Half of all bytes are negative. It's not clear that you have fully described the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am a novice on the subject. I have java source with debug, I'm trying to write Pascals. sorry my poor english

Comment: Your English is fine. I think you haven't fully decoded the representation. A Java long is 8 bytes not 5. Then is no Long. Can we trust that your code is correct. Anyway you are looking to convert from network byte order to host byte order. There are bespoke functions for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a record from host to network byte order (big endian)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505211/how-to-convert-a-record-from-host-to-network-byte-order-big-endian)

Comment: java byteBuffer Data.putLong interested in Pascal.

Comment: David you are right in the 8 bytes long, the mistake I made earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pascal equivalent of Java `long` is `Int64`, and you also need to change endianness; for example

```
type
  TBufferData = array[0..15] of Byte;
  TLongBytes = array[0..7] of Byte;

procedure putLong(var Buffer: TBufferData; L: Int64);
begin
  Buffer[0]:= TLongBytes(L)[7];
  Buffer[1]:= TLongBytes(L)[6];
  Buffer[2]:= TLongBytes(L)[5];
  Buffer[3]:= TLongBytes(L)[4];
  Buffer[4]:= TLongBytes(L)[3];
  Buffer[5]:= TLongBytes(L)[2];
  Buffer[6]:= TLongBytes(L)[1];
  Buffer[7]:= TLongBytes(L)[0];
end;
```

Note also that `byte` is a signed type in Java, it's direct equivalent in Pascal is `ShortInt` (`Byte` is an unsigned type in Pascal).

Comment: Thank you very much, perfect solution.

Comment: I'm not very keen on this. I'd regard this as a host to network conversion and use htonll.